# Geração de txt, não funciona função PHP_EOL

Tags: php, txt, exportação

Bom dia pessoal. Estou trabalhando em uma página php para geração de um arquivo.txt de exportação de dados para ser importado novamente em outro sistema.
Eu havia programado levando em conta o servidor rodar php 7, mas efetivamente foi colocado num servidor php 5.
O problema neste caso é que a função PHP_EOL que deveria por uma quebra ao final de cada linha não está tendo função.
Esse é o código:

```
//gera o arquivo
$DadosProposta = '1|'.$_SESSION['Parametros']['cdEntidade'].'|'.$_SESSION['Parametros']['dtAnoProcesso'].'|'.$_SESSION['Parametros']['nrPregao'].'|'.str_replace('-', '', str_replace('/', '', str_replace('.', '', $_POST['nrDocumentoLicitante']))).'|'.strtoupper($_POST['nmLicitante']).'|'.$_POST['flMPE'].'|'.$_POST['tpAmbito'].'|'.str_replace('-', '', str_replace('.', '', $_POST['nrDocumentoRepresentante'])).'|'.strtoupper($_POST['nmRepresentante']).PHP_EOL;

$Propostas = $_POST['Proposta'];
foreach ($Propostas as $Proposta ) {
    if($Proposta['vlProposta']!=''){
    $DadosProposta.='2|'.$_SESSION['Parametros']['cdEntidade'].'|'.$_SESSION['Parametros']['dtAnoProcesso'].'|'.$_SESSION['Parametros']['nrPregao'].'|'.$Proposta['nrLote'].'|'.$Proposta['nrItem'].'|'.str_replace('-', '', str_replace('/', '', str_replace('.', '', $_POST['nrDocumentoLicitante']))).'|'.number_format($Proposta['vlProposta'],$_SESSION['Parametros']['nrCasasDecimais']).'|'.strtoupper($Proposta['dsMarca']).PHP_EOL;
    };
};
$DadosProposta = trim($DadosProposta,'\r\n');
$nmArquivo = 'files/PropostaDigital'.$_SESSION['Parametros']['nrPregao'].'_'.$_SESSION['Parametros']['dtAnoProcesso'].'_'.str_replace('-', '', str_replace('/', '', str_replace('.', '', $_POST['nrDocumentoLicitante']))).'.txt';
$PropostaDigital = fopen($nmArquivo,'w');
fwrite($PropostaDigital,$DadosProposta);

fclose($PropostaDigital);

//força o donwload no cliente
    header("Content-Type: application/txt");
    header("Content-Length: ". filesize($nmArquivo));
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($nmArquivo));

    readfile($nmArquivo);

//exclui o arquivo do servidor
unlink($nmArquivo);
```

Na prática o resultado deveria sair assim, por exemplo:

```
1|12310|2020|29|22222222215487|M A FRIGHETTO EMPREENDIMENTOS|1|1|11146578987|MATHEUS AUGUSTO FRIGHETTO
2|12310|2020|29|1|1|22222222215487|12.00|
2|12310|2020|29|30|1|22222222215487|20.00|MMAR
2|12310|2020|29|31|1|22222222215487|300.00|LOL
```

Porém, o arquivo está sendo gerado assim:

```
1|12310|2020|29|22222222215487|M A FRIGHETTO EMPREENDIMENTOS|1|1|11146578987|MATHEUS AUGUSTO FRIGHETTO2|12310|2020|29|1|1|22222222215487|12.00|2|12310|2020|29|30|1|22222222215487|20.00|MMAR|2|12310|2020|29|31|1|22222222215487|300.00|LOL
```

Além de por alguma razão ainda mais estranha, estar sendo incluso um caractere html no início do arquivo, e de mesmo depois de fechado o arquivo ele continuar escrevendo código html dentro desse arquivo.
Quando fiz no meu computador pessoal estava gerando tudo certinho, mas ao ser colocado no servidor da empresa está acontecendo isso e não sei mais o que fazer.

Comment: PHP_EOL é uma constante, e não uma função. Essa constante representa a quebra de linha padrão do sistema operacional, normalmente não serve para a finalidade descrita (a não ser por coincidência, o que normalmente não é desejável). Precisa verificar a quebra necessária para o sistema que vai usar os dados, e não a do OS, e definir explicitamente no código.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o objetivo é enviar uma quebra de linha para o HTML use a tag [`<br>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br)

```html
<span>Quebra de linha<br>dentro dum<br>texto</span>
```

Se o seu objetivo enviar uma quebra para o console use a sequencia "\r\n" que funciona em múltiplas plataformas.

```js
console.log('Esse é um teste\r\nsobre quebras de linha\r\nindependentes de plataforma \r\nem seu código JS');
```

---

O problema se dá por conta da definição da constante [`PHP_EOL`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php):

> PHP_EOL ( string ) O símbolo 'Fim da linha' correto para esta
>   plataforma. Disponível desde o PHP 5.0.2

`PHP_EOL` é o símbolo 'Fim da linha' para o Sistema Operacional do **Servidor**. O que faz que não seja reconhecido pelo cliente. Ou seja essa constante é para ser utilizada em strings de uso interno do servidor e não possuindo aplicação em código cliente.

Só por curiosidade aqui está o código em C que que gera a constante a constante `PHP_EOL`

```c
//php.h:

#ifdef PHP_WIN32
#   include "tsrm_win32.h"
#   ifdef PHP_EXPORTS
#       define PHPAPI __declspec(dllexport)
#   else
#       define PHPAPI __declspec(dllimport)
#   endif
#   define PHP_DIR_SEPARATOR '\\'
#   define PHP_EOL "\r\n"
#else
#   if defined(__GNUC__) && __GNUC__ >= 4
#       define PHPAPI __attribute__ ((visibility("default")))
#   else
#       define PHPAPI
#   endif
#   define THREAD_LS
#   define PHP_DIR_SEPARATOR '/'
#   define PHP_EOL "\n"
#endif
```

<sup>Fonte: https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/main/php.h</sup>

> Uma quebra de linha é uma quebra de linha Uma quebra de linha é uma
>   quebra de linha, exceto quando não é. Surpreendentemente, existem três
>   tipos diferentes de quebras de linha no mundo da computação moderna e
>   o OS X usa dois dos três.
>
> Pode-se pensar que a inocente quebra de linha, aquele espaço em branco
>   dócil que nos diz quando os parágrafos começam e terminam, seria uma
>   peça relativamente simples de engenharia da computação. Infelizmente,
>   há mais na quebra de linha do que aparenta.
>
> Existem três tipos diferentes de quebras de linha, todos originalmente
>   exclusivos dos principais sistemas operacionais: Windows / DOS,
>   Macintosh e Unix. Um documento usando quebras de linha do Mac ficaria
>   horrível em um sistema Windows, e um documento usando quebras de linha
>   do Windows no Unix também não seria interpretado corretamente. A causa
>   disso é como a quebra de linha é realmente criada. O Mac, por padrão,
>   usa um único retorno de carro ( ), representado como \r. O Unix,
>   por outro lado, usa um único avanço de linha ( ) \n,. O Windows
>   vai um passo além e usa os dois, criando uma combinação ( )
>   \r\n.
>
> Para tornar as coisas ainda mais interessantes, até o surgimento do OS
>   X, as quebras de linha específicas do SO permaneciam em seu próprio
>   ambiente e não funcionavam bem com outras pessoas. O Windows entendia
>   apenas seus irmãos, o Unix ria loucamente de qualquer outra coisa, e o
>   Mac apenas sorria conscientemente. O OS X, no entanto, entende tanto a
>   quebra de linha original do Mac quanto a quebra de linha do Unix.

<sup>Dornfest e Hemenway: Mac Hacks. Tradução minha.</sup>

Answer (score -2):

usa ao final da linha:

```
"\n"
```

testei em meu ambiente local e funcionou assim, não esqueça de colocar entre aspas duplas.